# SQL query with ALTER TABLE print error #1064 in query execution

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table, generated-columns

I've built an SQL query in Aruba MySQL database using the alter table Statement to generate a new column with comma-separated values. I'm trying to automate the concatenate function every time a new record is submitted into the database table. After I execute the query I always get a #1064 error.

```
ALTER TABLE 1459630_form_1
    ADD COLUMN 'datimarketing' 
        MEDIUMTEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(`segmento_auto_richiesto`,',',`alimentazione`,',',`km_annui_percorsi`,',',`modalit_di_acquisto`,',',`budget_di_spesa`,',',`rata_mensile`,',',`abitudini_di_acquisto`,',',`numero_di_componenti_del_nucleo_familiare`,',',`hobby`,',',`professione`,',',`iscritto_ad_associazioni_di_categoria`,',',`privacy_mkt_all`,',',`giorno_preferito_per_il_ricontatto`,',',`orario_preferito_per_il_ricontatto`)) STORED AFTER `orario_preferito_per_il_ricontatto`
        UPDATE TABLE(1459630_form_1)
```

Somebody could help me?
Thanks

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag, since you obviously are running MySQL. Please always tag just one database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL the syntax goes like:

```
ALTER TABLE 1459630_form_1
    ADD COLUMN datimarketing MEDIUMTEXT 
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT_WS(',', `segmento_auto_richiesto`, `alimentazione`, `km_annui_percorsi`)) STORED 
    AFTER `orario_preferito_per_il_ricontatto`
;
```

I shorten the number of concatenated columns to make the code more readable (but the logic is the same of course).

Rationale:

- the column name should not be surrounded with single quotes
- parentheses need to balance
- `UPDATE TABLE()` is not applicable here

Side note: `CONCAT_WS()` comes handy to shorten the `CONCAT()` expression.

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested but I get this error" #1583 - Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat_ws'"

Comment: @FrancescoMarcucci: a comma was missing. Fixed.

Comment: I've modified the code ad follow: ALTER TABLE 1459630_form_1
 ADD COLUMN datimarketing MEDIUMTEXT 
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(`segmento_auto_richiesto`,',',`alimentazione`,',',`km_annui_percorsi`,',',`modalit_di_acquisto`,',',`budget_di_spesa`,',',`rata_mensile`,',',`abitudini_di_acquisto`,',',`numero_di_componenti_del_nucleo_familiare`,',',`hobby`,',',`professione`,',',`iscritto_ad_associazioni_di_categoria`,',',`privacy_mkt_all`,',',`giorno_preferito_per_il_ricontatto`,',',`orario_preferito_per_il_ricontatto`)) STORED AFTER `orario_preferito_per_il_ricontatto`
;

Comment: after every new submission, I get a string with NULL values